# Sort Multiple columns Alphabetically in SQL

Tags: sql, database

There is a table named books which has two columns,

- text column **title**
- text column **author**

How to get both columns sorted alphabetically.

**Input:**

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id Int,
  title Varchar,
  author Varchar
);

INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("Alice in Wonderland", "Lewis Carroll");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("Elements", "Euclid");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("The Extended Phenotype", "Richard Dawkins");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Isaac Newton");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions", "Edwin Abbott Abbott");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("The Emperor's New Mind", "Roger Penrose");
INSERT INTO books (title, author) VALUES ("Romeo and Juliet", "William Shakespeare");
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Alice in Wonderland
Elements
Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions
Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica
Romeo and Juliet
The Emperor's New Mind
The Extended Phenotype
Edwin Abbott Abbott
Euclid
Isaac Newton
Lewis Carroll
Richard Dawkins
Roger Penrose
William Shakespeare
```

Comment: Please add what have you tried.

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different options here.)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the with clause then union your two inline views.

```
with t1 as (select title as colA from books order by title),
t2 as (select author as colA from books order by author)
select * from t1 union all select * from t2
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CUeX8fnp2cHgi7iRzyL73/0